# Showing $\left| \oint \frac{\sin z}{z^{5}}dz \right| \leq 2e\pi$

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, cauchy-integral-formula

> Show that
> $$\left| \oint \frac{\sin z}{z^{5}}dz \right| \leq 2e\pi $$

**My attempt:**

I solved the integral without the absolute value, but I don't know how to get to the inequality. I also don't know if my calculations are correct.

$$f^{(n)}(z_0)=\frac{n!}{2\pi i}\oint_C \frac{f(z)}{(z-z_0)^{n+1}}\,dz$$

Here, we have $f(z)=\sin z$, $z_0=0$, $n=2$. Therefore, we have
$$
\oint_{|z|=1} \frac{\sin z}{z^{5}}\,dz=\pi i\left.\frac{d^4\sin z}{4!}\right|_{z=0}=0
$$

Thank you

Comment: It seems to me you are incorrectly applying Cauchy's formula. If $f(z)=\sin z$ then you should take the fourth derivative of $\sin z$, not of $\cos z$, and the integral is simply zero.

Comment: The question does not mention a contour. Is it meant to be the unit circle?

Comment: well, yes, zero has a smaller absolute value than $2\pi e$, but it seems to be the wrong answer to the wrong question.

Comment: @uniquesolution thanks. Can I put that the integral is zero and therefore less equal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that the contour in question is the unit circle, we have $|\sin(z)| \le e$ for $|z| = 1$, and $|z|^5 = 1$. Therefore,

$$\left|\oint_C \frac{\sin z}{z^5}\right| \le \text{length}(C) \sup_{|z|=1}|\sin z| = 2\pi e$$

Of course, since $\sin(z)/z^5 = z^{-4} + \tfrac{1}{6}z^{-2} + h(z)$, where $h$ is analytic on the unit disk, the integral is in fact zero. So this is not a very useful bound!

Edit: $\text{length}(C) = 2\pi$ is the length of the unit circle. For the bound, notice that $\sin(z) = \tfrac{1}{2}(e^{iz} - e^{-iz})$, so $|\sin(z)| \le \tfrac12(|e^{iz}| + |e^{-iz}|)$. But also, $|e^{x+iy}| = e^x$, and if $z$ is on the unit circle, then the real and imaginary parts of $z$ are between -1 and 1. Therefore $|e^{iz}| \le e$, and $|\sin(z)| \le e$.

Comment: The question says explicitly that integration is over $|z|=1$, but regardless, this is an overkill, as the integral is equal to zero.

Comment: @uniquesolution I don't think it's a very good question (not the OP's fault), but I wouldn't call bounding an integral overkill compared to the residue theorem.

Comment: It is Cauchy's formula, not the residue theorem. And not mentioning that the integral is zero is pure Trumpism.

Comment: Haha, Trumpism! I'll add a note.

Comment: @preferred_anon Please could you explain to me why \le \text{length}(C) \sup_{|z|=1}|\sin z| = 2\pi e.  :(

Comment: @davidhernandez I added some detail

Comment: @preferred_anon Thank you. <3